# How to read from a file an array

Tags: python

I have some array that i wrote on a txt file, an array like this:

```
[ 121.6  114.7  117.9  122.1  114.8  121.2  115.3  116.3  116.   121.
  115.3  120.8  114.4  115.5  116.9  127.7  119.4  118.1  116.3  115.3
  119.5  115.7  116.1  114.3  119.   116.   114.2  340.8  114.6  116.6
  118.5  114.1  121.3  120.6  116.3]
```

and another array like this

```
[[122.54227 ]
 [123.13425 ]
 [122.04907 ]
 [122.696365]
 [123.1821  ]
 [121.818115]
 [123.11479 ]
 [121.908745]
 [122.193954]
 [121.94495 ]
 [122.76871 ]
 [121.7559  ]
 [122.98235 ]
 [121.78393 ]
 [122.06499 ]
 [122.05317 ]
 [123.91927 ]
 [122.679565]
 [123.07596 ]]
```

is it possible using read file to return to this array form?

Comment: There are no commas between the array elements in the text file?

Comment: Yes it is possible, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Give it a try and show us with your attempt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, read and store the contents of the file like this:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    filearray = myfile.read()
```

If the contents of `filearray` is formatted as a valid python list (eg. `[1, 2, 3, 4]` or `[[1], [2], [3], [4]]`), you can directly use [`literal_eval` from the `ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
outputlist = literal_eval(filearray)
print(type(outputlist),outputlist)
```

Output:

```
<class 'list'> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If the list values in the file are not comma separated, you can use a regular expression to format it into a valid list (demo: https://regex101.com/r/4aO40h/2):

```
filearray = re.sub(r"(?<!\[)[,\s]+(?!\s*])(?=.*\w)",", ", filearray)
outputlist = literal_eval(filearray)
print(type(outputlist),outputlist)
```

Output:

```
<class 'list'> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I tryed with the not comma separated form but i have this error: File "<unknown>", line 1
    [117.7, , 118.1, , 119.4, , 121.6, , 114.7, , 117.9, , 122.1, , 114.8, , 121.2, , 115.3
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Please include the contents of your file in your post, so I can adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: now it seems working but why i have something like ([1 2 3]), is "(" and ")" a problem? or it is still a 1d array

Comment: It created a tuple `( , )` with the list as first element, because `re.sub()` added a comma at the end of the list. I edited my code accordingly. If it still outputs a tuple, you can just add `if(type(outputlist) is tuple): outputlist = outputlist[0]` at the end of the code to get the list.